# Equalizing the column widths in the rows below the title row of a grid

Tags: grid-layouts

I have a grid I've created with the first row set up as the title to the grid. The problem I'm having is that when the title is wider than the following rows need to be, Mathematica extends the final column of the lower rows to be wider. I'd really like to tell it to space the lower rows evenly, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've been fiddling around with ItemSize, but I just can't seem to land on the correct solution. I have included a code sample and the output I'm getting from it here.

```
With[
 {bbEEDdPercent = "31.2%", bbEeDdPercent = "62.5%"},
 f4g = x_String :> Style[Text[x], 25];
 Grid[{
   {Style[UnderBar[Text["Dilute-factored Chocolate"]], 35, Bold], 
    SpanFromLeft}
   , {"bbEEDd" /. f4g, bbEEDdImage, bbEEDdPercent /. f4g}
   , {"bbEeDd" /. f4g, bbEeDdImage, bbEeDdPercent /. f4g}
   }, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> All]]
```

[image: results of above code (images included when I ran it)]

Comment: Specify the `ItemSize` for the numeric cells, e.g., `Item[bbEEDdPercent /. f4g, ItemSize -> {Scaled[.2], Automatic}]`?

Comment: or  add `ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.4], Scaled[.4]}, Automatic}` after `Frame->All`  in your posted code.

Comment: Try using ``ImageSize->All``, and possibly adjust the [`Spacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacings) option as well.

Comment: @kglr, your second suggestion worked beautifully. I had to tweak the numbers a bit, but that's what I needed. Thanks so much!

Comment: crlast86, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use option `ItemSize` in several ways.

```
With[{bbEEDdPercent = "31.2%", bbEeDdPercent = "62.5%"}, 
 f4g = x_String :> Style[Text[x], 25];
 Grid[{{Style[UnderBar[Text["Dilute-factored Chocolate"]], 35, Bold], 
    SpanFromLeft}, {"bbEEDd" /. f4g, bbEEDdImage, 
    bbEEDdPercent /. f4g}, {"bbEeDd" /. f4g, bbEeDdImage, 
    bbEeDdPercent /. f4g}},
  Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Frame -> All, 
  ItemSize -> {{3 -> Scaled[.1]}}]]
```

[image]

`ItemSize -> {{3 -> 6}}` gives

[image]

`ItemSize -> {{1 -> 12, 2 -> 10}}` gives

[image]

**Note:** Somehow, in version 9, specifying  item sizes for all three columns doesn't give the expected result. However if you modify the first gird entry to

```
Style[UnderBar[Text["Dilute-factored Chocolate"]], 35, Bold, LineBreakWithin -> False]
```

then you can use a setting like `{{Scaled[.2], Scaled[.3], Scaled[.1]}}` to get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `ItemSize->{{3->6}}` and `LineBreakWithin->False` and the combination of these two fixed my issue. I'll need to do some more reading on why that worked in case I ever have the problem again. Thank you so much!

Comment: @crlast86, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says `ItemSize -> All` makes all the columns evenly spaced. Use this for the column size.

```
With[
 {
  bbEEDdPercent = "31.2%",
  bbEeDdPercent = "62.5%"
  },
 f4g = x_String :> Style[Text[x], 25];

 Grid[{
   {
    Style[UnderBar[Text["Dilute-factored Chocolate"]], 35, Bold], 
    SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft
    },
   {"bbEEDd" /. f4g, bbEEDdImage, 
    bbEEDdPercent /. f4g}, {"bbEeDd" /. f4g, bbEeDdImage, 
    bbEeDdPercent /. f4g}
   },
  Alignment -> {Center, Center},
  Frame -> All,
  ItemSize -> {All, Automatic}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]